# Rewriteengine in .htaccess to catch files not ending in html

Tags: html, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to use mod rewrite in to convert web page addresses like **/directory** to **/directory/index.html**, in a standard LAMP hosting situation. What I have works for addresses that end in a slash. I can't find a way to handle **addresses that don't end a slash**.

What seems like it should work is:

```
rewriterule ^(.*)/$ $1/index.html [L] /* addresses ending in / */
rewriterule ^(.*(?!html))$ $1/index.html [L] /* where the problem is */
```

But the second line causes a 500 server error. If I add a single letter x to the second line:

```
rewriterule ^(.*)/$ $1/index.html [L]
rewriterule ^(.*x(?!html))$ $1/index.html [L]
```

It starts to work, but **only for directory names that end in an x**. I have tried replacing the x with many different things. Anything more complicated than real characters (like [^x] or .+) gives a 500 server error.

And, to satisfy my own curiosity, does anyone know why the addition of a single real letter makes the difference between a server error and a perfectly functioning rule?

**[Accepted Answer]** Thanks to Gumbo I was able to approximate a solution using rewritecond:

```
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^/]+$
rewriterule (.+) $1/index.html [L]
```

This works, but filters more than just .html -- it could block other pages. Unfortunately,

```
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
```

results in a server error:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.

**I'd still like to know why:**

```
rewriterule ^(.*(?!html))$ $1/index.html [L]
```

results in a loop. The first half is supposed to check if it *doesn't* end in .html. Since the second half *adds* .html, it seems like the functional equivalent of:

```
while(substr($address,-4)!='html') $address.='html'
```

Obviously I'm missing something.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could name the server error.

Comment: Haven’t you read my edit notes? The look-ahead assertion looks in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `RewriteCond` directive to check whether the URL path does not end with a `.html`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])?/?$ $1/index.html [L]
```

---

**Edit**   You’re using a look-ahead assertion (`(?!…)`). But there isn’t anything after `.*` (only a `$`). So try a look-behind assertion instead:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$(?<!html) $0/index.html [L]
```

But note that you probably need Apache 2.2 to use these assertions.

Comment: This suggestion created a 500 server error, and I'm not expert enough to know wny. I'm going to look into it in more detail and edit this comment later.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for actually making it work, you could just use a negative lookbehind instead of a lookahead:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?<!html)$ $1/index.html [L]
```

I'm not sure offhand why adding the 'x' makes it work, I'll edit if I figure it out.

Comment: This suggestion created the same 500 server error as my original proposal -- and again it only worked if I added a random letter before the (?.

Answer (score 1):

For why adding the `x` makes it work:
If the replacement will match the regex, the RewriteRule will be applied again. As an example, this causes an error:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.rb
```

because it would replace `script` with `script.rb`. That matches the regex, so it replaces `script.rb` with `script.rb.rb`, again and again...

This is hinted at in the error log:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.
```

In your example, you add index.html to the end. When there is an `x` at the end of the regex, then it won't match your replacement, which ends in an `l`.

Comment: It shouldn't do this in the sample provided by andrew as the [L] at the end of the line should prevent it.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I didn't see the [L] there. I've edited my answer so it doesn't state anything wrong. I'll look at it more to see if I can figure out the actual reason. Thanks.

Comment: I see how this example creates a loop, but I don't see how it applies to my question -- what I'm trying to do is "if the address doesn't end in .html, add.html to the address". How does the [L] affect that?

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox: I've been testing, and it seems [L] doesn't stop the loop. [L] must just prevent *other* RewriteRules from being applied. The docs state "Stop the rewriting process here and don't apply any more rewrite rules."

Comment: @Andrew: You were wondering why adding x to this line -- rewriterule ^(.*(?!html))$ $1/index.html [L] -- made it work. Adding the x prevents it from looping. The negative lookahead doesn't do anything because .* already matches the whole thing, so the lookahead is tested against emptyness.