# Rewrite condition catchall if the URI doesn't start with this

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

So I have this rewrite condition at the bottom of my .htaccess file as a catchall.  works great, but I want it to ignore any requests and begin with "/index.cfm"

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.+) /index.cfm?event=baduri&uri=$1
```

so /index.cfm?fddssds would not be touched

but /gdfgdfgdfdgf would be redirected..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Can you try this and let me know:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.cfm
RewriteRule (.+) /index.cfm?event=baduri&uri=$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a RewriteCond directive to check whether the URL path does not start with /index.cfm

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.cfm
RewriteRule (.+) /index.cfm?event=baduri&uri=$1
```

See this question:
[Rewriteengine in .htaccess to catch files not ending in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604012/rewriteengine-in-htaccess-to-catch-files-not-ending-in-html)