# Redirect internally if host matches to certain hosts list via htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I want to redirect internally to a different directory/module within the site when my hostname matches a certain list of hosts or regex.

**For Example**

`http://fa.foo.com/controller/action/params` should be internally redirected to `http://fa.foo.com/module_name/controller/action/params`

**Please find my code and configuration below**

**OS**: Windows 10 (64Bit)

**Mod_Rewrite**: I have enabled Mod_Rewrite Module In Apache

**Codeigniter Version**: 3.1 (HMVC Architecture)

**PHP version**: 5.6.32

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    # Codeigniter default redirect config. This works perfectly fine.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    # My code for the above scenario.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fa.foo.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/index.php/module_name/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**application\config\config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'fa.foo.com';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

With the above htaccess code, the system throws below apache error

```
[Fri Apr 30 13:07:25.163464 2021] [core:error] [pid 6200:tid 1916] [client 127.0.0.1:64947] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I am sure I missing something. Any suggestions/help would be really appreciated!

Kindly let me know if any additional information is required.

Thanks!

Comment: This is currently completely lacking any actual _problem description_. (And if you are tempted to say “doesn’t work” now, please go read [ask].)

Comment: Thanks! @CBroe for taking the time to go through the question, really appreciated. I have updated the question. Can you please point out specifically what is missing, I will surely try my best to update the same. Thanks again!

Comment: Why does your substitution URL start with `%{HTTP_HOST}/`?

Comment: You are redirecting “everything” by matching `^(.*)$`, this would match the already rewritten URL again. You need to implement a check, whether the current URL path does not already start with what you wanted to redirect to, otherwise you’ll get an endless loop.

Comment: @CBroe ```%{HTTP_HOST}/``` is added to point to the host. I have removed that. Still, it is the same. Yes, I realized that, can you please help me with how can I add the check to avoid too many redirects? I am not much familiar with the ```.htaccess``` config. That would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9254046/1427878