# rewrite rule not working on usernames ending with letter h

Tags: .htaccess

I have a rewrrite rule for www.amunzi.com/profile.php?username=anyusername

```
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+[^.php])$ profile.php?username=$1  

> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+[^.php])/()$ profile.php?username=$1
```

It works fine, but the problem is that when a username ends with the letter 'h', it gives a 404 error.

Comment: I don't think "usernames ending with h" is the exact rule. You need more test cases. What are your test cases?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604012/rewriteengine-in-htaccess-to-catch-files-not-ending-in-html/604178#604178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex: `^([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+[^.php])$` will match any non-empty string of {alphanumeric characters or `._-`} followed by any character except `.`, `p`, `h` or `p`.

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

The rewrite condition should match all URLs not ending with `.php` [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/604178/499214) and the regex in the rewrite rule will match any non-empty string of {alphanumeric characters or `._-`}.